# Getting the density matrix of a noisy state in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming

Currently, it seems that qiskit can only compute the density matrix for a pure state. On the other hand, for noisy state, the known way to deal with it is to do sampling, which can induce great cost. So, I want to know is there a way to get a density matrix for a given circuit with specific nosiy model in qiskit?